# Controlling column mapping with a custom convention in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a class `TypeEntity` that will act as the base class for several dozen entities.  I'm using TPC, so I need to map all the properties on the base class to the table with the name of the concrete class, and set the `Key` field to be database generated.

Currently I'm doing this with an `EntityTypeConfiguration` for each entity type that looks like this:

```
class LineItemType : EntityTypeConfiguration<Models.LineItemType>
{
    public LineItemType()
    {
        this.Property(e => e.Key)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Map(e => e.MapInheritedProperties()
                       .ToTable(nameof(LineItemType)));
    }
}
```

This works fine, but is very repetitive. I have to remember to create a configuration class for every type that inherits from `TypeEntity`, set the key, and map the inherited properties.  This seems like an ideal case for a custom `Convention`.

---

I created a `TypeEntityTpcConvention` `Convention` as follows:

```
class TypeEntityTpcConvention : Convention
{
    public TypeEntityTpcConvention()
    {
        this.Types<TypeEntity>()
            .Configure(e => e.Property(p => p.Key)
                             .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity));
    }
}
```

Which works to set `Key` as database generated, but I can't find any way to access the table mappings for properties from inside a convention.

---

Ideally, I'd expect something like this:

```
this.Types<TypeEntity>()
    .Configure(e => e.MapInheritedProperties()
    .ToTable(e.ClrType.Name));
```

Or even a call like this for each property that needs to be mapped:

```
this.Types<TypeEntity>()
    .Configure(e => e.Property(p=>p.Key)
                     .ToTable(e.ClrType.Name));
```

Neither of which seems to exist.  Is there any way for me to control the mapping of properties from inside a `Convention`?

---

After some additional research, it looks like there are more advanced convention options available as `IStoreModelConvention` and `IConceptualModelConvention`, but useful documentation for how to use these is severely lacking. After several hours poking through them with breakpoints and watch windows, I haven't figured out how to control column mapping using these interfaces either.

---

My current solution is to use reflection to find all types that inherit from `TypeEntity` in `OnModelCreating`, and map the properties to the correct table.  This works, but I would prefer to use a convention if possible, as this really seems like the type of thing conventions were made for.  I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Comment: The problem isn't getting the name of the class, it's that `.ToTable` (or something else that allows me to redirect a property to a different table) doesn't seem to exist within the context of a `Convention`.

Comment: Ahh.. I misunderstood. I will delete the comment.

Comment: I have a solution. It's not exactly a convention, but it does apply automatically to all types that you specify (i.e. you don't have to add a new line of config for every entity). If you are interested, I can post it.

Comment: Do you really need TPC and not simply base class hierarchy? Because the only benefit of TPC are the automatic polymorphic (union) queries.

Comment: @IvanStoev I believe so. TPH would store everything within a single table.  I want every everything that comes from `TypeEntity` to be in its own, completely self contained, separate table.  The sub-classes really are unrelated to each other. I'm using the base-class simply because each one has the exact same schema.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I meant no EF inheritance at all. You can use base classes without EF inheritance. So the question is, do you have/need `DbSet<TypeEntity>` / `IQueryable<TypeEntity>`. If not, then simple configuration like in grek40 answer would work.

Comment: @IvanStoev Hmm, I was not aware of that.  So keeping the base-class, but leaving out the `DbSet` for it, will automatically put everything in to its own table, as if there was no base-class at all?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Indeed :)

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can see, you could just write the type configuration in the `OnModelCreating` method of your `DbContext` and it is very similar to the code you already mentioned in the question.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Types<TypeEntity>().Configure(c =>
    {
        c.HasKey(p => p.Key);
        // probably not needed, but won't do any harm
        c.Property(p => p.Key).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        c.ToTable(c.ClrType.Name);
    });
}
```

If there is any problem with this approach, let me know and I'll re-visit the topic.

**Edit:**

The exact same principle can be applied with conventions:

```
class TypeEntityConvention : Convention
{
    public TypeEntityConvention()
    {
        this.Types<TypeEntity>().Configure(c =>
        {
            c.HasKey(p => p.Key);
            c.Property(p => p.Key).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            c.ToTable(c.ClrType.Name);
        });
    }
}
```

and

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<TypeEntityConvention>();
}
```

Comment: This would have been my solution too. Not a convention, but it's generic without reflection.

Comment: I like your solution better than the reflection based one I'm currently using, but this really feels like something a `Convention` should be able to handle.  At this point, I have a workable solution, and it is just my desire to learn how  to effectively use conventions, that is keeping this question open for now.

Comment: @grek40 Won't `c.ToTable(c.ClrType.Name);` map the entire class to that table, rather than just the base-class fields?  I don't have access to my project to test.

Comment: You mentioned you use "TPC", so if your `DbSet` definitions target the actual type, everything should be fine - fine as in "map the entire class to that table"

Comment: The problem is that `MapInheritedProperties()` (essential for TPC) is available only through `Map` method which is not available in both suggested convention based approaches.

Comment: As far as I can see, the `Types<TypeEntity>().Configure(c => c.ToTable(c.ClrType.Name))` will take care of the property mapping for all `TypeEntity` properties to all concrete subtype tables. At least that just happened for my tests. I suggest you try it when you have access to your test project and we proceed from there. Note I create my test DbSet properties on the concrete types... if you create it on base types (not the best idea for TPC) things might be different.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not TPC, but TPT. The only difference between TPC and TPT setup is the `MapInheritedProperties()` which as I said in the previous comment is not available.

Comment: Note that without exposed `DbSet<TypeEntity>` (i.e. `TypeEntity` is not an entity, but simple base class), both your approaches work, but that's not EF inheritance at all. Which at the end might be what OP really needs :)

Comment: @IvanStoev you are right... I was kindof assuming the not really TPC approach because of the attempted `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`, which contradicts the single DbSet multiple tables approach. Maybe we can have a look at the question authors DbContext for more information.

Comment: Sorry to reply so late, but I didn't realize there was still an outstanding question in the comments of this answer.  I've solved my problem another way, but haven't rewarded the bounty yet, because I'd still like an answer involving conventions for future reference, it isn't really about solving my specific implementation.  I haven't seen any way to map individual fields to different tables via convention, which is what the bounty is for.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I don't really understand what you mean. My edit covers, how to apply the exact same configuration within a `Convention` that could otherwise be written into the `OnModelCreating` method.

Comment: @grek40 Your example shows how to map the entire entity to a table, not individual fields, as `MapInheritedFields` from within an `EntityTypeConfiguration<>` allows.